# CSS : Body border with rounded corners even after scrolling

Tags: css, reactjs

I am trying to display a body border on my screen with rounder corners on top to mimic for exemple the MacOS interface in the browser as the following image :

[image]

The problem is when I scroll, the top corners disappear :
[image]

Here is what i have html (though it is in react) :

```css
body:before,
body:after {
  content: "";
  position: fixed;
  background: #900;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

body:before {
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  height: 20px;
  top: 0;
}

body:after {
  bottom: 0;
  height: 10px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', 'Roboto', 'Oxygen', 'Ubuntu', 'Cantarell', 'Fira Sans', 'Droid Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  border-left: 10px solid #900;
  border-right: 10px solid #900;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="App">
  <div class="App-header">
    <span class="term-name">
          Header Title
        </span>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <p></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS is definitely not my strength and I am struggling to figure out how to do this...

Answer (score 1):

You can create the left and right borders using a linear gradient background, with `background-attachment: fixed`, so it won't scroll with the content:

```css
body:before,
body:after {
  content: "";
  position: fixed;
  background: #900;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

body:before {
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  height: 20px;
  top: 0;
}

body:after {
  bottom: 0;
  height: 10px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', 'Roboto', 'Oxygen', 'Ubuntu', 'Cantarell', 'Fira Sans', 'Droid Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #900 10px, transparent 10px, transparent calc(100% - 10px), #900 calc(100% - 10px)) no-repeat fixed;
  background-position: 0 10px;
}

.container {
  height: 200vh;
  padding: 0 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="App">
  <div class="App-header">
    <span class="term-name">
          Header Title
        </span>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent convallis est et eleifend facilisis. Aliquam rutrum libero vitae scelerisque varius. Vestibulum varius ipsum nisl, non elementum mauris feugiat in. Nam eget ultricies turpis, id aliquet
    risus. In lacinia neque odio. Morbi tincidunt elit egestas vulputate congue. Donec eget arcu quis lectus sollicitudin hendrerit viverra vitae orci. In vel sem sit amet augue egestas tincidunt quis ac libero. Nullam ut mollis justo, et gravida augue.
    Morbi elementum, sem ac tempor commodo, tellus lacus elementum risus, ac condimentum nisl nulla at orci. Donec suscipit, felis id iaculis ornare, risus ante imperdiet elit, a eleifend urna justo nec leo. Suspendisse fermentum malesuada mi non lacinia.
    Sed vitae erat ligula. In est tortor, iaculis a tincidunt eu, sodales et urna. Fusce at ante vitae risus fringilla auctor et in arcu. Nam mi ante, placerat at auctor sit amet, pretium ut urna. Integer id imperdiet enim. Sed pulvinar ligula viverra
    ultricies finibus. Ut nisl ligula, tincidunt sed risus porta, laoreet feugiat magna. Praesent laoreet felis in aliquet pretium. Donec sit amet enim faucibus, volutpat magna vel, cursus elit. Aenean sit amet nisl quis arcu ullamcorper facilisis. Nulla
    sed est eget turpis euismod dictum. Pellentesque posuere eu elit nec pulvinar. Maecenas eget congue ex. Mauris a laoreet arcu. Integer arcu mi, aliquet eu lacus tincidunt, vulputate commodo ipsum. Donec vitae nulla tincidunt, volutpat risus blandit,
    porttitor tellus. Duis id efficitur lacus, sit amet cursus orci. Donec eleifend mi a quam cursus porttitor. Phasellus egestas laoreet tristique. Nullam nec suscipit dui. Donec efficitur imperdiet ipsum at ullamcorper. Praesent ligula mi, suscipit
    elementum gravida eget, imperdiet egestas lorem. Aenean vehicula nunc sit amet pellentesque tincidunt. Vestibulum tellus enim, cursus nec mi pulvinar, sollicitudin euismod dolor. Duis lacinia faucibus velit quis elementum. Donec convallis mattis odio,
    vitae laoreet arcu. Phasellus eget nisi nibh. Nulla eu odio ligula. Nam lacus sapien, tincidunt vitae magna egestas, placerat efficitur sem. Phasellus massa nibh, placerat at accumsan ac, viverra congue ante. Nam non metus pulvinar magna convallis
    fermentum ut id mi. Proin ac mauris vitae sapien eleifend facilisis. Donec volutpat porta justo id porta. Duis semper nibh a diam condimentum, consequat tempus mi volutpat. Mauris ut ipsum ac leo laoreet ullamcorper sit amet ut neque. Sed dolor mauris,
    blandit elementum lobortis id, aliquet sed metus. Quisque a viverra nibh. Nullam accumsan interdum justo, vitae mattis dolor sollicitudin ut. Duis tristique libero sit amet sem congue, nec suscipit odio interdum. Quisque metus quam, euismod eu sem
    sed, mattis rhoncus augue. Praesent leo urna, placerat vel velit id, volutpat mattis eros. Maecenas ut mi justo. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In suscipit condimentum libero vel finibus. Sed id neque in metus sodales fringilla.
    Nam placerat, est euismod elementum blandit, nisi felis venenatis odio, nec sodales justo libero id nulla. Etiam finibus euismod pharetra. Pellentesque ac tincidunt nunc. Morbi convallis nec justo sit amet malesuada. Curabitur a mauris ac odio auctor
    eleifend. Nam ut magna elementum, hendrerit ipsum ut, rutrum neque. Sed vel mattis neque. Nullam finibus pulvinar justo et vehicula. Quisque id feugiat augue. Etiam varius, dui sit amet egestas cursus, dui erat vestibulum mauris, vel volutpat arcu
    dui a ipsum. In rhoncus ipsum porta lacinia vestibulum. Suspendisse potenti. Fusce iaculis nibh nisi, non varius erat fringilla ut. Fusce vel hendrerit ipsum. Nam varius ex elit, sed elementum augue tincidunt ut. Vivamus lobortis nulla dui, gravida
    dignissim neque porttitor non. Suspendisse dui metus, laoreet eu nibh non, venenatis viverra ligula. Maecenas suscipit nunc orci, eu pretium enim consequat a. Donec quis neque malesuada, laoreet leo non, ornare erat. Vivamus feugiat ullamcorper dui
    a porta. Maecenas ullamcorper, ante et laoreet interdum, sapien ipsum feugiat elit, at viverra neque tellus et libero. Donec non libero at nulla ornare lobortis non ac ligula. Nullam viverra egestas erat sit amet ultrices. Aenean vulputate tellus
    turpis, id imperdiet elit convallis ac. Mauris at elit urna. Nulla facilisi. Fusce vitae iaculis massa, sed ullamcorper urna. Mauris lacinia magna sed sollicitudin viverra. Aenean interdum tincidunt posuere. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis
    dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Curabitur ipsum tortor, scelerisque eget ipsum id, sagittis volutpat enim. Morbi congue nulla id porttitor hendrerit. Aenean hendrerit convallis leo, eget facilisis tellus luctus sed. Vestibulum ante
    ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Maecenas tincidunt vehicula sodales. Donec cursus ante tortor, quis convallis tortor commodo vitae. Duis pulvinar nibh purus, ac auctor dolor lacinia quis. Cras dictum, felis
    sit amet dictum dapibus, ex sem vulputate justo, in porttitor quam est eget odio. Aenean tempus aliquam mi, in iaculis quam ornare sit amet. Morbi sed turpis eleifend, euismod risus ut, laoreet lorem. Aenean lorem lectus, ullamcorper quis nisl sit
    amet, maximus facilisis mauris. Aenean nec maximus quam. Mauris risus felis, sodales et metus non, sodales faucibus ex. Aenean laoreet, ligula quis maximus volutpat, nisi nulla fringilla ipsum, accumsan vulputate turpis augue volutpat risus. Vivamus
    posuere tortor vel efficitur iaculis. Aliquam erat volutpat. Fusce consequat sollicitudin faucibus. Quisque rhoncus vel quam eget pulvinar. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nulla sed tempus sapien, sit amet imperdiet erat. Pellentesque tincidunt sodales ligula,
    quis scelerisque tellus ultrices at. In euismod ac diam id dictum. Aenean pulvinar massa sit amet congue fringilla. Nulla eget placerat neque. Quisque hendrerit urna quis justo pharetra, vitae finibus nunc tincidunt. Cras iaculis sapien a metus aliquet
    ornare. Nulla eget dolor neque. Nullam tristique lacus mauris, at hendrerit velit sagittis id. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Quisque ut velit quis lectus pretium ullamcorper a in elit. Nullam vitae semper mauris. Sed interdum, augue sed viverra
    vestibulum, diam lorem elementum metus, vulputate consectetur nisl ex vel arcu. Mauris interdum lectus ac magna eleifend aliquet. Mauris auctor viverra nisl id convallis. Pellentesque ut eros tellus. Morbi euismod risus vel urna eleifend, id sagittis
    leo finibus. Suspendisse aliquam odio et ultricies rhoncus. Donec vestibulum arcu ac dictum ullamcorper. Sed finibus sit amet metus vel accumsan. Nam luctus risus sed est pulvinar, vel faucibus dolor scelerisque. Etiam ac dui scelerisque, elementum
    ligula et, volutpat ante. Phasellus interdum lorem nisl, vel malesuada velit facilisis vel. Quisque risus nunc, posuere vulputate dolor sed, suscipit suscipit mi. Fusce a eleifend augue, quis rhoncus metus. Phasellus quis ornare dolor. Pellentesque
    quis arcu finibus, ornare ipsum sed, fermentum sem. Suspendisse eget pulvinar dolor. Fusce tempor vestibulum quam, id pretium magna aliquet quis. Donec vel risus ut nulla egestas luctus. Cras quis nisl at mauris consequat ullamcorper fringilla ut
    nunc. Integer commodo feugiat tellus sit amet efficitur. In ex nisl, dapibus eleifend hendrerit mollis, mattis eu libero. Nullam a feugiat lorem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam ac imperdiet lorem. Phasellus eu faucibus
    odio, id convallis diam. Integer eleifend augue facilisis, tincidunt mi sed, accumsan enim. In ultricies neque eget urna mollis suscipit. Etiam justo tortor, blandit ac tortor in, euismod euismod sem. Sed odio metus, consequat fermentum placerat sit
    amet, hendrerit at tellus. Duis congue vulputate sapien ut fermentum. Morbi maximus justo eu pellentesque porta. Cras maximus in mauris id semper. Etiam nec enim a leo ullamcorper scelerisque. Aliquam erat volutpat. Curabitur augue dui, dapibus eget
    egestas quis, tristique at nisl. Morbi sit amet metus imperdiet, aliquet felis malesuada, commodo justo. Nulla vitae urna eleifend, ullamcorper purus convallis, auctor tellus. Donec malesuada, lectus sed cursus consectetur, quam ante pulvinar est,
    sed faucibus nisi turpis vel massa. Vivamus euismod enim leo, eget maximus est convallis eu. Nam gravida mi ac laoreet consectetur. Integer sed dui sagittis magna sodales blandit.
  </div>
</div>
```